# Is it possible to create a thick Mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, vtk, trimesh

I'm totally new to this field, I'm using python and Trimesh to create a 3D model of a bone and I need to figure out how can I create or represent the thickness of the bone I only have surface of the bone which is ok, but I need also to represent how the bone looks inside this surface, Anyone has a clue on how to approach this problem?

Ask me if you need more information, I'm not sure what you need to know to understand the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem is not well defined.. you need to specify what is "thickness" and what information you have of the inside of the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [gmsh](https://gmsh.info/) along with [mmg](https://www.mmgtools.org/) to mesh in volume your surface.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need.

- if you want to display volumetric informations, you have 2 options:

  - generate a voxel filling the volume delimited by your surface
  - triangulate your volume with tetraedrons (I heard that [gmsh](https://gmsh.info/) was good for it)
- if you just want to have successive inner surfaces, you can use offseted/deflated surfaces

  this can simply be achieved by offsetting your first surface points along their normal
  you can use for instance `inflate` or `thicken` [here](https://pymadcad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generation.html#madcad.generation.inflate) from the pymadcad module